# ¿Como puedo cambiar el color de la cabecera de una TabControl?

Tags: c#, windows-forms

Mi problema es corto de explicar, lo que deseo es cambiar el color de la cabecera de un `TabControl`, pero C# no me da la opción de hacerlo, solo permite modificar el color de fondo de las paginas.¿Hay alguna `propiedad` que me permita modificar esto, o se debe hacer mediante código?.

PD: Soy novato publicando, les pido perdón si hay algo mal formulado, estoy aprendiendo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Analizando varios ejemplos llegaras a la conclusion que no hay una propiedad directa para cambiar el color, sino que deberas hacerlo usando codigo.

Para esto se debera

- Definie el evento `DrawItem`
- trabajar con [gdi](/questions/tagged/gdi) para redefinir el grafico de la solapa, usando `e.Graphics.FillRectangle()`, junto a `SolidBrush` para definir el color

Podria ser algo como esto

```
private void tabControl1_DrawItem(object sender, DrawItemEventArgs e)
{
    Graphics g = e.Graphics;
    TabPage tp = tabControl1.TabPages[e.Index];

    StringFormat sf = new StringFormat();
    sf.Alignment = StringAlignment.Center; 

    // Este sera el rectangulo que se dibujara sobre el titutlo del tab 
    RectangleF headerRect = new RectangleF(e.Bounds.X, e.Bounds.Y + 2, e.Bounds.Width, e.Bounds.Height - 2);

    // Este sera el color por defecto del tab no seleccionado 
    SolidBrush sb = new SolidBrush(Color.AntiqueWhite);

    // color del tab que se selecciona
    if (tabControl1.SelectedIndex == e.Index)
        sb.Color = Color.Aqua;

    // aplica el color sobre el tabpage actual 
    g.FillRectangle(sb, e.Bounds);

    //escribe el texto que tenia el tab 
    g.DrawString(tp.Text, tabControl1.Font, new SolidBrush(Color.Black), headerRect, sf);
}
```

como observaras se redibija el rectangulo del tab cambiandole el color

Referencias

[Is there a way to color tabs of a tabpage in winforms?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2107463/is-there-a-way-to-color-tabs-of-a-tabpage-in-winforms)

[How to set color for tabpage header in a tabcontrol ?](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/a2d68883-e5b8-47e9-a46b-6d8f0008086e/how-to-set-color-for-tabpage-header-in-a-tabcontrol-?forum=csharpgeneral)

[Como cambiar de colores el TabControl](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/es-ES/01ab8403-2e2e-43e6-82fd-7498961297d8/como-cambiar-de-colores-el-tabcontrol?forum=vbes)

[Set TabPage Header Color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5338587/set-tabpage-header-color)

Comment: Muchas gracias! Me pondre a "jugar" con el codigo asi aprendo su funcionamiento, y adaptarlo a lo que necesito en especifico.

Comment: Una ultima pregunta, pude modificar todo lo que quise, pero no se como modificar los margenes y fondos del resto del control y en las referencias no encuentro el codigo que se encarga de eso ¿conoces cual seria?